# PL/SQL Case When - Map input to other column values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've checked elsewhere on Stack but I couldn't find a similar scenario.

I want to essentially map 1 input from a PL/SQL procedure to 3 different values in MY_TABLE; otherwise I just want to filter on the input. I would like a solution similar to the below pseudocode

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE COLUMN 1 = 'B'
AND CASE WHEN p_input = 'F' THEN COLUMN_1 IN ('F','A','B')
         ELSE COLUMN_1 = p_input;
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing an `END`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend using `case` expressions in the `where`.  Just use simpler boolean logic operators:

```
WHERE COLUMN 1 = 'B' AND
      ( (p_input = 'F' AND COLUMN_1 IN ('F', 'A', 'B')) OR
        COLUMN_1 = p_input
      )
```

In particular, Oracle doesn't have a boolean type in SQL (there is on in PL/SQL).  So a case expression cannot return a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - I was more or less trying to write it how I would in OOP. What you've suggested make sense, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are learning how to use `case..when` in `where` clause then following is the code:

```
CASE WHEN p_input = 'F' AND COLUMN_1 IN ('F','A','B') THEN 1
     WHEN COLUMN_1 = p_input THEN 1
END = 1
```

But as suggested in other answer, it is recomended to use `or` And it is always a good idea to use negative condition `p_input <> 'F'` in second condition while using `OR` as follows:

```
( 
(p_input = 'F' AND COLUMN_1 IN ('F', 'A', 'B'))
OR
(p_input <> 'F' AND COLUMN_1 = p_input)
)
```